# How to keep data of draggable in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

*I changed the way I asked the question to fulfill SO requirements.*

I have similar `<div>` elements one after another with custom datas assigned to them via javascript (jQuery's data method).

I want user to drag 1 div element and drop it to another one for just replacing these 2 elements. Drag & drop process shall not change index positions of any other element.

Eg. In a set: {a,b,c,d,e} when user drags "a" on "d", the new set shall be {d,b,c,a,e}

Every single element shall keep it's custom data assigned when being created.

How can I do this?

Comment: This seems like an xy problem. Instead of describing what is not working with your attempt at doing something, describe what you're trying to do and mentioned what you've tried...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @TJ I think I have now fixed the xy-problem.